# Adding HashMap instead of using switch-case?

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have a Java class which has a number of switch cases which I now want to replace with HashMap, because of better performance. So earlier my switch case was something like :

```
SomeClass someMethod =  new SomeClass();

  if (!("".equals(varA))) {
                switch (varA) {
                case "3":
                    someMethod.setValue("abcd");
                    break;
                case "91":
                    someMethod.setValue("defgh");
                    break;
                        }
```

Now I want to replace this with the HashMap. I am struggling with adding the object in the put.

```
HashMap<String, SomeClass> hashMap= new HashMap();
hashMap.put("3", ?????);
```

What should I write there so my object sets the value ?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map<String, String>` and then `someMethod.setValue(map.get("thekey"));`?

Comment: Usually I'd guess a lambda, but not sure if Java has them

Comment: @ComradeBearabyte Java has lambdas since JDK 8.

Comment: If your unique goal is better performance, I doubt using a HashMap will change anything. You'd better strive for readability and correctness, and only care about performance once you have a performance problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I am using HashMap, since the number of cases in my switch-case block exceeds 20.

Comment: @AlexisC I am working on JDK 7, is this going to work in JDK 7.0 ?

Comment: @AnkushBhan Yes of course but why don't you try?

Comment: @AlexisC.So I did something like hashMap.put("3", "abcde")
someMethod.setValue(hashMap.get(key));

Comment: From a first glance it looks like you should use inheritance instead of switching on values.

Comment: Switch will almost always have better performance than a map. Why do you believe otherwise?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have like more than 30 cases, its a waste, and since my method gets initialized only once I can set the values in a HashMap and use them using static block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store `callbacks` as values of your hashmap:

```
public interface MyCallback { 
  public void doSmth( String val ); 
}

...

HashMap<String, MyCallback> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put( "42", new MyCallback(){
  @Override doSmth( String val ){ System.out.println( val ); }
} );

hashMap.get( "42" ).doSmth( "ultimate question" );
```

Comment: I would rather say 42 is the ultimate answer...  Unfortunately no one knows what the question is.

Comment: lets wait for another million years :)

Answer (score 1):

In your apparent switch case, you always call `someMethod.setValue("...")` with differing values, so this code can do the same:

```
private static final Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();

// in ctor: Fill values on first class instanciation only
if (values.size() == 0) {
    values.put("3", "abcd");
    values.put("91", "defgh");
}


// later
if (values.containsKey(varA))
    someMethod.setValue(values.get(varA));
else
    // Handle unknown switch case
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated for java 8:

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("42", s -> System.out.println(s));

map.get( "42" ).accept( "ultimate question" );
//or
Optional.ofNullable(map.get("42")).map(fn -> fn.accept("ultimate answer"));
```